# Find a list of people who participate in more than one circle

Tags: prolog

I'm just starting to work with Prolog, so I don't really understand it. I have the facts:

```
circle(сhess, abbot).
circle(сhess, hannigan).
circle(сhess, abrams).
circle(crystal_voice, blake).
circle(crystal_voice, weller).
circle(crystal_voice, huxley).
circle(local_studies, barnes).
circle(local_studies, haskins).
circle(local_studies, abrams).
circle(local_studies, aberdeen).
circle(art, barnes).
circle(art, abbot).
circle(art, blake).

person(abbot, male, 20).
person(aberdeen, female, 18).
person(weller, male, 22).
person(abrams, female, 25).
person(adams, male, 21).
person(bond, female, 12).
person(haskins, male, 15).
person(blake, female, 20).
person(barnes, male, 20).
person(hannigan, female, 15).
person(huxley, male, 18).
```

I need to solve the problem: Find a list of people who participate in more than one circle.

I have a code that finds only the number of circles that a person visits.

```
count(Name, Count):- 
   findall(1, circle(_, Name), List),
   length(List, Count).
```

Comment: Hint: You only need to know if the number of *matches* is *greater than 1*. Needlessly creating a list might save 1 or 2 lines of code, but is bad for performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beginner way is:

```
circles2(Person) :-
    circle(Circle1, Person),
    dif(Circle1, Circle2),
    circle(Circle2, Person).
    
circles2_people(People) :-
    setof(Person, circles2(Person), People).
```

... which produces the right answer:

```
?- circles2_people(People).
People = [abbot, abrams, barnes, blake].
```

... but is a little inefficient, due to `circles2` producing duplicates which `setof` then removes:

```
?- bagof(Person, circles2(Person), People).
People = [abbot, abrams, blake, barnes, abrams, barnes, abbot, blake].
```

So, can use as an optimization:

```
person_circles2(Person) :-
    person(Person, _, _),
    once(circles2(Person)).
```

The above code "loops" through the persons (due to backtracking), and tries *at most once* for each person to satisfy the `circles2` constraint - which does not **duplicate** the people:

```
?- bagof(Person, person_circles2(Person), People).
People = [abbot, abrams, blake, barnes].
```

However, one would still normally use `setof` instead of `bagof`, with the benefit of this optimization, to also be clear on intention:

```
?- setof(Person, person_circles2(Person), People).
People = [abbot, abrams, barnes, blake].
```

Comment: Thank you, your optimization will be useful for me in my next projects. Olso, about  dublicating. It was a good lesson for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Defining the first case (find a person who is in more than 1 circle) is easy:

```
person_in_multiple_circles(P) :-
    person(P,_,_),
    circle(C1,P),
    circle(C2,P),
    C1 \= C2
    .
```

That, however, will give you duplicate results.

Which you can winnow out with `setof/3`:

```
persons_in_multiple_circles(Ps) :-
  setof( P, person_in_multiple_circles(P) , Ps )
  .
```

But it might be easier to use `append/3` and `memberchk/2` and say something like:

```
persons_in_multiple_circles(Ps) :-         % To find the list of all persons in multiple circles, ...
    findall( P , circle(_,P) , P0 ),       % - find all persons in at least one circle, and
    findall( D , is_duplicate(P0,D) , Ps ) % - find all duplicates in that list
    .

is_duplicate( Xs , X ) :-                  % X is duplicated in Xs, if...
    append(_,[X|X1],Xs),                   % - X is found in Xs, and
    memberchk(X,X1) .                      % - X can be found further along in Xs
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, the explenation is simple and clear. Now I'm back in the game to learn more in/about this language :)